# How can I see all text in the day using fullcalendar in javascript?

Tags: javascript, text, fullcalendar

What do I need to do to see all the text in the day? For example, for the 15th, it says: "Prueba tarea de formulario", but I can see only "Prueba tarea de fo". I need to display all the text.

These are my options:

```
calendar: function(){

    var self = this;

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({


    events: self.objCalendar.json,

        header: {

        left: '',
        center: 'prev title next',
        right: ''

        },

    eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
        $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
        $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
        $('#fullCalModal').modal();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in your CSS whether you have something similar to this:

```
.fc-event-time, .fc-event-title {
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If you remove those lines in the CSS part of this [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybfeyrmj/), you'll see that FullCalendar adapts the event sizes to the title length.